# Google Maps not showing in Flask app as per tutorial

Tags: google-maps, flask, google-geocoding-api

I have made a Flask app that should technically load Google Map as per their [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

But to my surprise, everything works locally and on [hosted on Heroku](https://selflearning.herokuapp.com) and no error comes but maps don't load.

```
<div id="map"></div>
                     
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    var map;
                    function initMap() {
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            center: {lat: {{lat}}, lng: {{lng}}},
                            zoom: 16
                          });
                        console.log("map function");
                        console.log(map);
                    }
            </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{key}}&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

In the JavaScript console output, there are two prints: the first one says map function, second one is map object created of latitude and longitude passed to initMap function. This means the map object got created but did not updated div with map id!

None of the [error codes listed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#expired-key-map-error) on the Google page are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times this has something to do with the API Key. Make sure you created one the right way and that it is enabled and running. Hope I helped.

Comment: I have got key from google console under creditentials, ( I believe all API keys work on different type of google app ) and I have it restricted for the same domain name I have hosted on.

Comment: The API key should match your purpose. For example you if you want to add google maps on an android device and on a website you have to create a different key for each of those. Secondly, try not restricting your key. Create a google maps javascript key without any restriction and use this in your site.

Comment: Hello @Apostolis ,  I dont think it has something to do with API Key, because in console that will raise exception, I experimented and found out. However I have added more information in my opening post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I followed the tutorial step by step but it didn't work.

Chances are, you've installed flask_googlemaps using pip and chances are, pip didn't update the path to the latest version of flask_googlemaps.

**Here's how to fix the problem:**

1. pip uninstall flask_googlemaps
2. Download the package from [here](https://github.com/flask-extensions/Flask-GoogleMaps/releases/tag/0.4.1.1) (in case the link breaks, its in their github page, realse tag 0.4.1.1)
3. pip3 install path_to_the_package_you_just_downloaded
4. run your app, it should be working now!

This is the solution that worked for me.